# Invariant measure on coset space and integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, integration, topological-groups, abelian-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group, and $H$ a closed subgroup.  Let $C_c(G)$ be the space of continuous, compactly supported complex valued functions on $G$.  General theory of Haar measure says that the linear functional

$$\Phi: C_c(G) \rightarrow C_c(G/H)$$

$$\Phi(f)(gH) = \int\limits_H f(gh)dh \tag{1}$$

is surjective and its kernel contains the kernel of the functional $f \mapsto \int\limits_G f(g)dg $ on $C_c(G)$.  Therefore, there is a unique linear functional $\Psi$ on $C_c(G/H)$ such that $\Psi \circ \Phi(f) = \int\limits_G f(g)dg$.  By the Riesz representation theorem, $\Psi$ must be given by a measure on $G/H$, and this measure satisfies

$$\int\limits_G f(g)dg = \int\limits_{G/H} \int\limits_H f(gh)dh dg \tag{2}$$

for all $f \in C_c(G)$.

My question is, what can be said about (2) holding for more general functions, not necessarily compactly supported?  Say, $f$ continuous and in $L^1(G)$.  It isn't obvious that (1) even converges in this case.

If $f$ is continuous and integrable, and (1) converges for all $g \in G$, does (2) hold?

Comment: What you say is not entirely true. There's a condition. You need that the modular function of $G$ and $H$ agree on $H$. Then the whole thing goes through for $L^1$-functions as well, as is shown in Deitmar/Echterhoff: Principles of Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I wasn't aware of that.  By the way, if we assume $f$ is continuous and $L^1$, there is no reason to believe that the convergent integral $g \mapsto \int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Yes I think that's right.

Comment: Other reference: Bourbaki ([1963](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2005f:28001), translation p. [VII.42 c)](//google.com/books?id=6RrpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA31) with $\rho=1$ in your abelian case): if $f\in L^1(G)$, then (1) converges for $gH$ outside a null set of the measure on $G/H$, is integrable on $G/H$, and (2) holds.

Comment: If one wants this sort of thing in the context of "measurable functions", as opposed to distributions, recapitulating the Fubini-Tonelli discussion but in a "non-split" (and potentially non-abelian) sense should give the sharpest result, and at least suggest correct statements.